# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "std::terminate()", referenced from

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I got the error when i run `react-native run-ios` after upgraded RN to 0.26.0-rc.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext initWithJSContext:onThread:] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext invalidate] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      _RCTNSErrorFromJSError in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor context] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I recently had a similar issue with this, and I forgot that I had forgot to link a binary with libraries (in Build Settings). I would check if libReact.a got removed from there.

Comment: @BradBumbalough I checked it already. the libReact.a were there. There was no problems with other libraries.

Comment: You didn't by chance switch to using CocoPods recently, did you?

Comment: @BradBumbalough I did not using CocoPods. Are there some problems?

Comment: When I switched from linking Libraries to CocoPods I had a few issues (the libReact.a being one of them). You also have to open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: @BradBumbalough I did not using cocopods, so there is no `.xcworkspace`. :(

Comment: @BradBumbalough Could you pls explain a little bit how did you solve the problem? I am using Cocopods and I opened .xcworkspace. I have "-lc++" in Other Linker Flags. But having the same error as OP. I'm using RN 0.29.2

Comment: @deju are you still looking for an answer not presented? if not, would you kindly help me work towards my next badge now that this question has been open for over a year?

Answer (score 86):

Resolved with the [following advice](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7566#issuecomment-219226634) after running [`rnpm-plugin-upgrade@0.26`](https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm-plugin-upgrade):

> [...] add `-lc++` in `Other Linker Flags` in your xcode project build settings.

As pointed out in comments update *target* build settings (and not project). You may also need to update the Test target as well.

Comment: Yes, it is right.  But there are many problems in third plugins when i upgrade to 0.26.

Comment: I'm using cocoapods and that solved my problem as well.

Comment: Right, I added in "Build setting" of targets (not project)

Comment: same issue for me after upgrading from rn 0.25.1 to 0.28, and solved just with the flag added

Comment: You have to add it to the test target too (the default one), see https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7566#issuecomment-242034598. I had to select the "test" target as shown in the comment but also, had to switch the view from "basic" to "all" to be able to add it to "Other Linker Flags"

Comment: @damio Thanks. I've experienced the same and updated the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I had to add it to the test target too to get things working.

Answer (score 8):

When I add Facebook SDK to my project, these errors appeared:

```
Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: ___gxx_personality_v0
Undefined symbol: operator delete(void*)
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__next_prime(unsigned long)
Undefined symbol: vtable for std::length_error
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_rethrow
Undefined symbol: vtable for std::out_of_range
Undefined symbol: std::length_error::~length_error()
Undefined symbol: std::out_of_range::~out_of_range()
Undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__shared_weak_count::~__shared_weak_count()
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_end_catch
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_allocate_exception
Undefined symbol: std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for std::exception
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for std::__1::__shared_weak_count
Undefined symbol: operator new(unsigned long)
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_begin_catch
Undefined symbol: vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__shared_weak_count::__release_weak()
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for std::out_of_range
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for std::length_error
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_throw
Undefined symbol: std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
Undefined symbol: std::terminate()
Undefined symbol: std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const
Undefined symbol: ___cxa_free_exception
```

This solved my problem:
`Build Phases` -->`Link Binary With Libraries` --> Add '`libc++.tbd`'.

Comment: This helped to build test target in development pod. Pod had dependencies which required c++. This answer allowed to build even without linker flags like `-lc++`. On other side linker flags switching made no help for me.