# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in swift project

Tags: ios, j2objc, j2objc-gradle

I convert java to objective-c,and import it into a swift project by bridging-header file.
When i build the swift project, get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DTPeople", referenced from:
  type metadata accessor for __ObjC.DTPeople in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
```

I have set the correct dir for libjre_emul.a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64: "std::terminate()", referenced from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186967/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-stdterminate-referenced-from)