# Xcode std::__1::basic_ostream undefined symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, c++11, objective-c++

I built a static library, outside of Xcode, that I want to use in my Xcode project. I have added the library and it shows up under Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries as well as in General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

I have also added the following to General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries:

- libc++.tbd
- libbz2.tbd
- libc.tbd

I have also added the following flags in Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags:

- -ObjC
- -lz
- -lbz2
- -liconv
- -lc++
- -lstdc++

And finally under Build Settings -> Apple LLVM 8.1 - Language - C++ -> C++ Standard Library
libstc++ (GNU C++ standard library).

So I thought this was all I needed but when I try to build I get a compilation error:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream >& std::__1::operator<<, std::__1::allocator >(std::__1::basic_ostream >&, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from: ...

To me it looks like the C++11 standard library is not being linked in correctly and my static library needs it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined symbols for architecture x86\_64: "std::terminate()", referenced from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37186967/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-stdterminate-referenced-from)

Answer (score 2):

So my solution was to modify the static library so that it include standard lib inside of itself.
I am guessing that since this is a static library, and not a dynamic one, that it will always look for dependencies internally and even if they are linked externally.